# Raspberry Pi 3 USB Microphone Issues

Tags: usb, audio

I have a Raspbery pi 3 and trying to use a usb microphone (C-Media microphone USB) but having no success. The  "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf" is not found on my Raspberry pi, does this mean that it wasn't recognized? How can I get my USB microphone to work without having the file in the first place? I have looked at all other forums and they all point to the  "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf" file and I don't have that file. Should reinstall the OS and see if that works? Please help

Comment: Google to the rescue: see [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/989385/alsa-base-conf-missing-in-new-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jesse)

Comment: THANK YOU jogco!!!! Definitely helped alot, but can I actually edit this file though because I have tried before and it kept telling me permission denied

Comment: Excuse the late reply: you may edit the file by doing "sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf" ... Google how to use nano first. BR :)

Comment: alsa-base.conf no longer exist it is now alsa.conf and I tried that with the current OS but no success, have you seen this before? Is C-Media a good Microphone to use because doesn't get recorgnized by aplay -L